# Can't get my python script to work/play audio when executed in crom

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi3

I'm having lots of trouble with a pythron script that I'm trying to run through crom.
The python script does a few things. It starts by importing modules for SQL, grabs information from an SQL database, turns the information into a text-to-speech string, and then reads it out loud. I currently have the server and the script on a raspberry pi, and when I run the script through the command prompt, it works fine.

However, I can't seem to get the script to run through cron. I've never used cron before, so I don't know much about how to debug it. Whenever I use `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`, it tells me that its executed when it's supposed to, so it's difficult to tell if its an error with the script running, or if the audio isn't playing. I'm happy to try out any potential solutions, and I'm a beginner to crom, so I wouldn't be surprised if it was something minor that I haven't come across yet. Any help is appreciated!

Edit 1: Here is a minimal reproducible example:

My python script effectively is:

```
# python sql commands
import pymysql
import os
from gtts import gTTS

#Please keep in mind that this information is just a placeholder, and not what is actually in the script - the script works as intended
db = pymysql.connect(host = "localhost",user = "root",password = "", database = "mydb")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results
        name = row[0]
        atext = name
    speech = gTTS(text = atext, lang = "en")

    speech.save("speech.mp3")
    os.system("omxplayer -o local speech.mp3")
    db.close()
```

In the crontab, I have it set to run each minute:
`* * * * * python3 /path/to/file/"Assignment Grabber.py"`

The goal is for the python script to read the text out loud. It does this perfectly when I manually run the python script through the terminal. However, putting it into the crontab and waiting results with nothing.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question. Does the new edit help any?